# Eclipse, maven and wtp

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, maven-2, m2eclipse

I've installed the m2eclipse plugin with WTP integration in my eclipse workbench. When I use to run the project on a server, the dependencies which has to be provided at runtime (e.g. spring) are not deployed. Is this working like intended? Maybe some of you can provide me the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this working like intended?

No.

> Maybe some of you can provide me the right way.

Not with the level of detail you provided (like your POM, especially your spring dependency, your eclipse version, the m2eclipse version...).

P.S. On the basis of your wording, I suspect that you are using a *runtime* scope for some dependencies and you could face [MNGECLIPSE-1231](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNGECLIPSE-1231). If you do so for the Spring artifacts, then I don't know why and I'd suggest to use the *default* scope. But this is a big guess.

Comment: This bug fits my problem. Thanks for the advice Pascal.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project, select "Properties"

From the properties menu click "Deployment Assembly"

Click "Add" -> "Java Build Path Entries" then click "Next"

Select "Maven Libraries" on the list and click "Finish"